# Inconsistencies with Prettier

Tags: javascript, eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier-eslint

I have a Vue project, which is having some inconsistencies with its linting.

I'm using the latest version of VS Code.

For instance, this is a linting error I receive:

[image]

After saving the file, VS Code auto fixes so that the code looks is linted like this

[image]

However, when I try to run `npm run serve`

I get an error, asking to change it back.

```
error: Replace `(h)·=>·h(App),` with `h·=>·h(App)` (prettier/prettier) at src/main.js:91:11:
  89 |   router,
  90 |   store,
> 91 |   render: (h) => h(App),
     |           ^
  92 | }).$mount("#app");
  93 |
```

my .eslintrc.json file is

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest/globals": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "airbnb-base",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
    // "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    // "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "vue",
    "jest"
  ],
  "rules": {},
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.js",
        "*.vue"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "sort-imports": "off",
        "spaced-comment": "off",
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
        "import/no-unresolved": "off",
        "import/extensions": "off",
        "func-names": "off",
        "object-shorthand": "off",
        "eqeqeq": "warn",
        "prefer-const": "off",
        "camelcase": "off",
        "no-plusplus": "off",
        "no-else-return": "off",
        "consistent-return": "off",
        "no-restricted-syntax": "off",
        "no-shadow": "off",
        "prefer-destructuring": "off",
        "no-return-assign": "off",
        "guard-for-in": "off",
        "jest/no-disabled-tests": "warn",
        "jest/no-focused-tests": "error",
        "jest/no-identical-title": "error",
        "jest/prefer-to-have-length": "warn",
        "jest/valid-expect": "error"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and my VSCode settings.json file is

```
{
  "eslint.codeAction.showDocumentation": {
    "enable": true
  },
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "remote.extensionKind": {
    "pub.name": ["ui"]
  },
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "vue", "html"],
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,

  "eslint.run": "onSave",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "prettier",
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true,
  "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.stylus": "none",
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Community Material Theme Darker",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1
}
```

I'm guessing there must be a project vs vs code inconsistency, but I can find it.

Using `npm run serve` auto fixes the file, however, if I save the offending file again, suddenly it pops up with linting errors all over again (which then cause the Vue app to crash in dev).

I've tried `npm cache clear --force` and changing permissions on node modules, and reinstalling them, but no luck.

I think I need to tell my local rules to override prettier, but am unsure how to do so

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `eslint-config-prettier` to turn off eslint rules that conflict with prettier. Make sure to also include the `prettier/vue` rules

https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier

```
 "extends": [
   "plugin:vue/essential",
   "airbnb-base",
   "plugin:prettier/recommended",
   “prettier”,
   “prettier/vue”
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

## To solve conflict

You can make eslint accept all the prettier formattings by installing eslint configuration for prettier

```
npm install eslint-config-prettier
```

And include it in the `extends` option in the file `.eslintrc.js`

```
extends: [
  ...,
  "prettier",
],
```

Now it won't complain on the prettier format preferences